# Authentication design treating first party JavaScript app and third party apps consistently

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am going to build a web service with all resources exposed via RESTful API. I will have my own database of users and the main way they are going to access the web service will be through a web site which I will also write. The web site will consist of HTML pages and JavaScript which will make calls to the API.

There will also be third party applications which will be able to access the API, given the user authorizes them to do so via my authorization server (which I plan to be physically identical to the API server). So using OAuth 2.0 seems like a good fit here.

To reduce the complexity and improve the maintainability, I would like to treat my own web site in the same way I am going to treat the third party apps with regards to authentication and authorization.

This, however, raises some concerns which I was not able to address to my satisfaction so far. The following issues relate to the web site of mine, not to the third party apps as they in fact will have a simpler job in my opinion.

Using OAuth means appending access token with each request. I can obtain the access token by having the user provide his username and password and using the [implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) flow. But

1. Implicit grant does not support the issuance of refresh tokens. So either I will force the user to login again from time to time, destroying the user experience or issued access token will have a *really* long expiration period.
2. The JavaScript app will have to store the access token somewhere. I do not have an experience with how this works, but I presume a session or a local storage is used to achieve this. But then if an attacker gains access to the user's browser, he can send valid API requests on his own since he will probably be able to read the access token. Are the [CSRF prevention measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention) enough to avoid this? Or should I just give up and assume that once anyone gains access to the user's browser, all hell breaks loose and there is no point addressing this threat in any extra way?

I have read so much about this over the last few days that I am overwhelmed with information and cannot make my mind on the definite solution. If I did not have to support third party applications eventually, I would probably go with just setting a Forms authentication cookie which would be appended automatically by the client to each request and that would be it. But I do not want to have double logic for validating the requests (access tokens for third party apps and cookie for my own website).

There are people who [discourage the implicit grant altogether](http://alexbilbie.com/2014/11/oauth-and-javascript/)...

> Please please please just avoid the implicit grant, it's a bag of hurt for everyone and it's just not worth implementing if you care even slightly about user experience and security.

...which further adds uncertainty to my decision.

All communication will use only HTTPS, of course.

**Edit**: The [official ASP.NET tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) on how to secure an API using OAuth also uses the flow described above for a website (except they use the "Password" grant type and not the "Implicit" one), so maybe I am overthinking this and should just take this route.

Comment: What was the solution you did implement on this one?

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo I haven't gotten to this yet and it is no longer something I am going to implement anytime soon, but I would still like to know what the correct solution is.